# Distinct Record Issue in MS SQL Server 2008 query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query to fetch the total OrderStatus that have values 1 and 5. How do I Sum only distinct OD.OrderStatus=2 as there can be multiple records in Orderdetails table with OrderStatus as 2.

Please help

```
SELECT O.OrderDate,
Sum(Case When OD.OrderStatus = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS OrdersOffered,
Sum(Case When OD.OrderStatus = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS OrdersAccepted
FROM Orders O,OrderDetails OD
Where O.Order_ID=OD.Order_ID
GROUP BY OrderDate
```

Comment: Please provide some example data and the results that you are looking for.  So far, the description(s) that you are giving seem either incomplete or contradictory and we cannot figure out what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want it to be 1, regardless of how many you have? Maybe use SIGN?

```
SELECT O.OrderDate
  ,SIGN(Sum(Case When OD.OrderStatus = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End)) AS OrdersOffered
  ,Sum(Case When OD.OrderStatus = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS OrdersAccepted
FROM Orders O
  JOIN OrderDetails OD  ON O.Order_ID=OD.Order_ID
GROUP BY OrderDate
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I need SUM(Sign(Case When OD.OrderStatus = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End)) AS OrdersOffered
I need to try it tomorrow. I don't know if it will work

Comment: No. Suppose you have ten OrderStatus = 2 records. SUM(SIGN( will add many 1s to get 10. You want to convert the 10 (Sum) back to a 1. So it's SIGN(SUM(, not SUM(SIGN(.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Here is my concern. The above query I have a date range in where clause. It returns for each date in the range it will display orderdate,ordersoffered,ordersaccepted.

But OrderID 10010 may have 10 orders with status as 2 but it should consider only 1 but for the same date The sum for OrderIDs 10010, 10011,10012,10013  should be 3 and not 1.
Thanks

Comment: but Sign(Sum(Case When OD.OrderStatus = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End)) will always return 1 right?

Comment: You're grouping by OrderDate. So if you want at most 1 for each OrderDate, then SIGN will help. SIGN gives either 1, 0, or -1. So if you have three OrderStatus=2 for yesterday, none for today, and one for tomorrow, you'll have: yesterday, 1. today, 0. tomorrow, 1

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery to help with your result.

```
SELECT 
O.OrderDate, 
Sum(Case When OD.OrderStatus = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS OrdersOffered, 
Sum(Case When OD.OrderStatus = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS OrdersAccepted 
FROM Orders O inner join
    (Select distinct Order_ID,OrderStatus 
    from OrderDetails) OD on O.Order_ID=OD.Order_ID
GROUP BY OrderDate
```

Should do the trick...